# Android: How to get a thumbnail image of a map centered on a given location?

Tags: android, google-maps

Is there a lightweight way to dynamically generate a thumbnail image of a map centered on a particular longitude/latitude via a Maps API call?

(My use case is a ListView displaying a ranked list of locations. I want to customize the ListAdapter so each view also displays a thumbnail map of that location. Pressing the thumbnail then takes you to the fullblown map..)

Babak

Answer (score 12):

Try this, check by hitting this link in browser:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=29.390946,%2076.963502&zoom=12&size=600x300&maptype=normal

Adjust attributes according to your requirements.